# Position:relative for anchors in webkit broken. Work-arounds?

Tags: css, webkit, css-position, anchor

In our project we used the following method to link users to some anchorred area on the page:

```
<span style="position: relative; top: -100px; z-index: -1; visibility: hidden;"
                   id="anchor">&nbsp;</span>
```

This was used to leave a little space before the exact anchorred element like a form.

[image]

But since some late version of Safari this has broken and browser is positioning at the initial position of the element with no regard to the relative position.

Maby you have met this feature/bug too and have some work around to propose or can point out why my method is bad.

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't use span tags to add space.  You're inventing your specific own uses for markup.  CSS is not legos - you could add this extra space to the element in question - you don't need to create and append another element to get more space.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just add the `ID` attribute to the element in question, i.e. `FORM`? If you want to add vertical spacing before the form, you can use CSS:

```
<form id="anchor" style="margin-top: 100px;">
 …
</form>
```

Issue eliminated, and much cleaner code :)

Comment: Cause i want to have a gap before the exact form. It make ui usability better a bit.

http://gyazo.com/5caf56e2ce48db0a599ad5aa28919a43.png

Comment: Why not use form#anchor { margin-top: 100px; } then?

Answer (score 0):

Yep! hanks to the incorrect but usable answer by [Developer Art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151323/developer-art) i got the solution!

If i apply id and relative position to the **DIV** anchoring to the #id starts working with telative scroll!